# Are questions about adaptation and rule changes to other mediums allowed?

Tags: discussion

For example I want to adapt a game to play by forum and wanted to find any rule changes that may be implemented to optimize for forums.

Comment: Mediums? *Mediums*? Perhaps you're looking for "media"? :-)

Answer (score 4):

That seems on topic to me. But be careful: that kind of question could be considered primarily opinion-based depending of how you ask it. Try to put objective goals in it so the answers can be judged based on those goals.